# How do I calculate the third point of a triangle in a 3Dimensional Plane

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, kinematics

I am attempting to create a system that will replicate arm movement, so far I have mastered this in a 2D plane however I am having trouble adding the third dimension. Here is what is given, You know the location of two points (shoulder and hand) as well as the lengths of the upperArm and foreArm. I need to find the coordinate of the elbow.

To simplify it say the elbow is always 180 degrees relative to the hand when looking head on to them both. Essentially creating the triangle on a plane parallel to the Y/Vertical axis

this is what I'm aiming to do, if you need to simplify it greatly then do so please.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8u0JUpst3w

Comment: I think you need to specify more information. You have, if I'm correct, $AB$ and $BC$ where $A$ and $C$ are fixed. You wish to find $B$, but this is not unique.

Comment: what exactly is the info is it that is needed. To simplify it say that the elbow,  hand, and shoulder when looked at from above could have a straight line drawn through them, does that give enough parameters to find the elbows point? (What do you mean unique?)

Comment: As in the answer below, the elbow could be anywhere on a circle. I think if you specify an initial location for the elbow, some point on this circle, then you can should be able to track the subsequent motion from there.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can’t.

The elbow could be anywhere on a circle centered on and perpendicular to the line joining the two known points. You’ll need some other piece of information to nail it down.

*Update:* Per your comment to the question, you do have additional information, namely, that all three points lie on a plane that’s perpendicular to the ground. If you can determine this plane, then your problem reduces to the one you’ve already solved.

A simple approach is to work directly in coordinates relative to this plane. Let’s put the shoulder at $x_S' = 0$. The Pythagorean theorem gives us the $x'$-coordinate of the hand: $$x_H'=\sqrt{(x_H-x_S)^2+(y_H-y_S)^2}.$$ Apply your 2-D solution using the points $(x_S',z_S)$ and $(x_H',z_H)$. This will give you coordinates $(x',z)$ in the arm plane that you can map back to $(x,y,z)$ in 3-D via similar triangles.

This still leaves you with two possible solutions, but presumably you've already dealt with this in the 2-D case.

Comment: what if I say the elbow stays at 180 degrees relative to the hand/shoulder, if you need to set your own parameters then do so.

Comment: Could you write out the equation for getting the x and z coordinates? Or more simply at least show how I would determine the plane, and apply it?

Comment: @LoganHunt See the latest edit.